# Compile-time access to class template's member by index

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, template-meta-programming, compile-time-constant

Given a template whose non-type parameter determines the size of a non-const `int` array member, how can I access the array elements by an integral index at compile time? I want the access to be done via the class template’s getter method `at`.

I figured since class templates must be instantiated before runtime, I can pass another non-type class template’s `enum` member value to the prior class’s `at` method to ensure the `index` argument is a compile-time constant.

I left the class template `deliberate_error` undefined to see if its arguments are computed at compile time and to view the compile-time results in the error messages.

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct compile_time_int {
    enum {num = N};
};

template <unsigned int N>
struct array_wrapper {

    int arr[N];

    template <unsigned int Ind>
    constexpr int const& at(compile_time_int<Ind> const& index) const {
        return arr[index.num];
    }
};

template <unsigned int> struct deliberate_error;

int main() {
    compile_time_int<2> cti;
    array_wrapper<3> aw;
    aw.at(cti);
    deliberate_error<cti.num> my_error1;
    deliberate_error<aw.at(cti)> my_error2;
}
```

`aw.at(cti);` doesn’t give an error, so I thought that if I passed the same expression to `deliberate_error` instance `my_error2`, the compiler will display the value of `arr[2]` in the error message.

`my_error1` causes g++ `error: aggregate 'deliberate_error<2u> my_error1' has incomplete type and cannot be defined`,

showing `cti`’s wrapped integral value `2`. So, I thought if I passed the same `cti` to object `aw`'s getter, and then pass the result to `my_error2`, I can get `arr[2]` in the error message. But instead, it prints:

```
error: the value of 'aw' is not usable in a constant expression
note: 'aw' was not declared 'constexpr'
note: in template argument for type 'unsigned int'
error: invalid type in declaration before ';'
```

So, I tried prepending `constexpr` to `aw`’s declaration, but that gives even more undesirable errors. What’s wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: *"So, I tried prepending constexpr to aw’s declaration, but that gives even more undesirable errors."* That sounds like the right thing to do, also see remyabel's anwer. What errors do you get? (Note: you'll need to initialize `cti`, even if it's just with `{}`, and you need to do the same thing, `constexpr` + initializer, for `aw`.)

Comment: `compile_time_int<N>` seems like a reinvention of [`std::integral_constant<int,N>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)

Comment: @remyabel I think you're on the right track, both `aw` and `cti` need to be declared with `constexpr` and initialized.

Comment: @DyP, these were the errors: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b314af2d534f7390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note that as far as I see, [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) with [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get) already solves your problem.)

---

The main issue is that you need your instance `aw` to be `constexpr` and of course you need to initialize it with some values:

```
constexpr array_wrapper<3> aw = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Regarding the function `at`, you can write it as a normal function but simply specify it as `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int const& at(int i) const {
    return arr[i];
}
```

Then, `aw.at(0)` can be used as a constant expression: [**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/qe1kHQ)

The advantage of this is that you can use this function in both compile-time and runtime expressions, with static and dynamic indexing, respectively.

---

If you really want it to be templated, you can either write it as a non-member like `std::get<N>` or as a class member, but use a template parameter of type `int` (or `size_t` or similar). That simplifies its definition (and you can get rid of your `compile_time_int` class template):

```
template<int Index>
constexpr int const& at() const {
    return arr[Index];
}
```

Then, `aw.at<0>()` can be used as a constant expression: [**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/2Mwhak)

The advantage of the second method is that the index is guaranteed to be static, so we can use it in the function for static bound checking, which will not add any performance penalty. I don't know if this is possible with the first version.

Comment: Why does `aw` need to be initialized if it has a default ctor? How did you initialize `aw` with a `braced-init-list` of 3 values if its only ctor is the compiler-provided one?

Comment: For POD types, the compiler implements a c'tor taking the members in their order AFAIK. So it's an `int[3]` in this case. And `{ 1, 2, 3 }` can be used as an initializer for `int[3]`. It might be possible that this only works since C++11. -- The reason why it has to be initialized is if you add constexpr, the compiler needs to know the value during compile-time. For POD types this means you have to initialize it with the members, as explained above. If you wrote your own default c'tor (without args) then you can write `constexpr array_wrapper<3> aw;` but this c'tor has to be constexpr too.

Comment: That being said, constexpr aside, if you don't initialize POD types at all, they have uninitialized content. You can assign values to it later on, so the content is well defined. But `constexpr` has to be initialized right away; the compiler will not analyze your program to see if it will be assigned later. Remember: constexpr is evaluated at compile-time; the control flow is intentionally designed to be very limited when this functionality was added to C++ with C++11.

Comment: I thought the compiler initializes POD `array[]`s that the programmer didn’t explicitly initialize. Wouldn’t that allow the compiler to know the garbage values it initialized the array with?

Comment: `std:array` is insufficient since its `operator[]` is not required to be `constexpr` in C++11, only in C++14.

Comment: @Casey With [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get) it works, but the template syntax instead of the (in my opinion) nicer function parameter syntax.

Comment: @CodeBricks The garbage content depends on the memory content at runtime. So it's not known at compile-time, so the C++ constexpr feature requires an initialization. Everything else doesn't make any sense. Why would you want the compilation process to be dependent on garbage?

Comment: The problem of `constexpr a_w<3> aw;` is the same as for `const a_w<3> aw;`: variables declared `const` require an initialization. Just writing `some_type name;` invokes default-initialization. For class types, this invokes the default-constructor. A "compiler-provided" default-constructor recursively default-initializes the bases and members. Default-init of built-in types and arrays thereof means **no** init. Therefore, the default-ctor might not initialize anything. `constexpr` strictly enforces init, `const` only requires a user-provided default-ctor (to make a non-init case explicit).

Comment: Btw: `array_wrapper<3> aw = { 1, 2, 3 };` is just plain-old aggregate-initialization, as `aw` has no non-defaulted constructors. Aggregate-initialization is already available in C++98 and C.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just this:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct array_wrapper
{
    int arr[N];
};

template <unsigned int I, unsigned int N>
constexpr int & at(array_wrapper<N> & a)
{
    static_assert(I < N, "static array index out of bounds");
    return a.arr[I];
}

// add a "const" overload, too
```

Usage:

```
array_wrapper<10> x;
at<3>(x) = 42;
```

Comment: This now looks pretty much like `std::array` combined with [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get). I think you could make that `at` a `constexpr` function.

Comment: @DyP: Good point. Yes, it was sort of my point trying to highlight the large amount of wheel reinvention on part of the OP...

Comment: @KerrekSB, +1. Thanks. Your answer is elegant, but the accepted one showed specifically where my code went wrong.