# How to implement a compile time getter, for a more concise call?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, compile-time-constant, constant-expression

I want to implement a compile-time getter in a way to make its call more concise. I have a non-type (`unsigned int N`) class template `foo`, which recursively inherits from `foo<N - 1>`. Every `foo` has its own `enum` member called `number`, which is initialized to the value of its corresponding `N`. The base case is `foo<0>`. For example, a `foo<5>` object has 6 `enum`s called `number`, valued `0` through `5`. I want to implement a compile-time getter `at`, but it's not as easy as prepending a `constexpr` to the prototype:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct foo : protected foo<N - 1> {
protected:
    enum {number = N};
public:
    constexpr int const& at(const unsigned int index) {
        static_assert(index <= N, "out of range");
        return this->foo<index>::number;
    }
};

template <>
struct foo<0> {
protected:
    enum {number = 0};
public:
    constexpr int const& at(const unsigned int index) {
        static_assert(index == 0, "out of range");
        return this->number;
    }
};
```

In g++ 4.8, I get several instances of the errors: `error: 'index' is not a constant expression`, among other things. The rest just follow suit. Even if all client code calls `at` with integer literals only, the getter won't compile. Why?

In any case, my solution was to implement a compile-time integer wrapper. It's simply a non-type (`unsigned int N`) class template `ctint` (short for compile-time int), whose `enum` member `mem` is initialized to its `N`:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct ctint {
    enum {mem = N};
};
```

So, replacing `foo<N>` and `foo<0>`'s getter methods, respectively, with:

```
template <unsigned int ind>
constexpr int const& at(ctint<ind> const& ctint_par) {
    static_assert(ctint_par.mem <= N, "out of range");
    return this->foo<ctint_par.mem>::number;
}
```

and

```
template <unsigned int ind>
constexpr int const& at(ctint<ind> const& ctint_par) {
    static_assert(ctint_par.mem == 0, "out of range");
    return this->number;
}
```

works:

```
int main() {
    foo<5> f;
    static_assert( f.at( ctint<4>{} ) != 4 , "equals 4");
}
```

but makes the function call verbose. I’d like an implementation that’s library-free aside from parts (e.g. `<iostream>`) that show something works but not help make it work. I’d like the getter to be able to optionally omit or have no `<>` syntax or spelling out of a type name in the call, but not necessarily in the prototype or definition. I don't want it to involve `array[]`s. If that’s impossible, I’d like to know the next-best way.

Comment: Why can't you just do `template<uint N> constexpr int at() { ... }`?

Comment: @0x499602D2, I'd prefer not to involve `<>` syntax in the call.

Comment: It's the only way you've narrowed it down to. You have to supply it as a template argument.

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20724456/596781)?

Comment: @KerrekSB, I'm not sure if the prior's solution applies here. The difference is I don't want to use arrays or `<>` syntax in the call here. Though the integer wrapper is re-implemented here, I don't think they are the same question. The inheritance recursion makes that prior question's accepted answer's getter inapplicable here.

Comment: @0x499602D2, Why doesn’t the first, broken `at` code work even if I call it with an integer literal? A call to a normal non-member `constexpr int bar(int index) {…}` works with a literal within a `static_assert`. Why does the `N` cause a literal passed to `index` to **not** be a compile-time constant?

Comment: Regarding the first example, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17577749/420683). Essentially, a function parameter of a `constexpr` function is not *assumed* to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: `template<unsigned int N> using ctint = std::integral_constant<unsigned int, N>;` (i.e. it already exists in the Standard Library). Also, the `const&` aren't useful as far as I can see in these examples.

Comment: What about user-defined literals? `f.at( 4_cint )` [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67dff34294a8a225)

Comment: @DyP, [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14248310/2090317) says: "`constexpr` functions will be evaluated at compile time when all its arguments are constant expressions and the result is used in a constant expression`." If my code fails to compile, preventing me from instantiating any objects, how would it know I planned to call my getter with a non-literal or call it with a literal and not use the result in a constant expression?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but the `constexpr` function itself must be written in a way so that it *can* be called with arguments only known at run-time. That's why it isn't assumed that the parameters are compile-time constants.

Comment: It must also be written so that if for *some arguments*, if those arguments are known at compile-time, the function can be evaluated at compile-time. E.g. in a constant expression. But nothing is assumed about when the function is actually called later; it just has to satisfy those two requirements: 1) for some arguments, it must be evaluable at compile-time 2) it must be evaluable for arguments known only at run-time.

Comment: @DyP, +1 for pro code.In my broken code, if I pass literal to `at`, then it’s known at compile-time.But compiler errors remove my chance to pass literal to `at`. I [**commented out stuff here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/200ec1341efce1a7) so that `index` isn’t used to look up base subobjects. Is that the difference for the function's constant-expression-ness? I’m guessing the compiler doesn’t allow possibility of using `index` to look up subobjects since there’s possibility `at` is called at runtime with wrong value, evaluating nonexistent bases.Is this un-SFINAE for function bodies?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309245/single-expression-helper-for-compile-time-enforced-constexpr-function-evaluation?

Comment: Your first `constexpr` function using `return this->foo<index>::number` violates the second point I mentioned: At run-time, there *are no templates and no types*, `foo<index>` **must** be resolved at compile-time. And that's of course not possible if we don't assume `index` is a compile-time constant (initialized with a constant expression). Similarly, `static_assert` is a compile-time feature. However, instead of `static_assert`, you can [throw an exception to raise a compile-time error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8626450/420683).